# Generating a printable letter with called variable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

Im completely lost on this, can I create a letter on a Report in visual basic then call a specific text from a textbox in another form or call a result from sql query cause printing is not an issue anymore on report or do I have to create a print button then generate the letter in there then call a specific text from a texbox in another form? If so how does the syntax goes?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add some punctuation to your text. It is very hard to read it. Also, be more specific about what you want to do. What do you mean by calling a text?

Comment: Sorry about the punctuations, what i meant was how can you put a variable in the generated letter

Comment: I have tried creating a letter in Report but cant put some variables in

Comment: You mean string concatenation like `"Start of letter ..." & variable & " ... letter continues ..."`?

Comment: @Nico yes exactly

Comment: So, that hint was apparently not what you were asking. What exactly is your question? Your question is on a very high level, which allows a multitude of interpretations of what you are actually doing. Could you add some code to illustrate your problem? Btw, don't feel sorry about the punctuation. Use the edit button to correct it.